# Why does find command in if return "paths must precede expression" error?

Tags: linux, shell, ksh

Below is my ksh script.  I am getting `paths must precede expression` error for the first if test condition.  To check if I have the correct syntax for if..find, I added the second section and I correctly get the message `pass 2 - found files`.

I also verified that the below find command runs successfully and returns me the correct files that I want.  I tried putting double quotes around PAY*.txt and also backslash before asterisk 'PAY*.txt' but no luck.

```
find -iname 'PAY*.txt' -newermt '2021/04/22 00:00' ! -newermt '2021/04/22 23:59' -print
```

I am guessing the issue might be with the p_date1 and p_date2 being passed but again I don't know enough and unable to resolve it.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
#!/bin/ksh

p_date1='2021/04/22 00:00'
p_date2='2021/04/22 23:59'

if test -n "$(find -iname 'PAY*.txt' -newermt $p_date1 ! -newermt $p_date2 -print)";
then
  echo 'Files exist to upload'
else
  echo 'No Payment files exist to upload'
fi

if test -n "$(find -iname 'PAY*.txt' -ls)";
then
  echo 'pass 2 - found files'
else
  echo 'pass 2 - no files'
fi
```

Thanks.

Comment: Just put a dot ('starting from this directory') as the argument preceding `-iname`.

Comment: I cannot explain why you're seeing `pass 2 - found files`.  Perhaps the code you show here is not the code you actually ran, or you have some non-standard `find`.  Normally, you would write `find /p/a/t/h -iname ...` to tell `find ` the directory to look in.

Comment: @Roadowl Yes, I tried a dot and same error for the first if and success for second if.

Comment: @WilliamPursell This is the code.  I did not change anything.

Comment: [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) automatically detects this problem of unquoted variable expansion

Comment: @thatotherguy WOW -- that ShellCheck site is amazing!  I pasted the above code and it gave the exact solution.  Thanks a lot for sharing!  I am making that site viral :-)

Comment: And now it is clear why you are getting `pass 2 -found files`.  You are using a non-standard version of `find` which defaults to using `.` for the search path when no paths are given.  Stop relying on gnu foibles, and tell gnu maintainers to stop violating standards.  Grrrrr.

Comment: @maskeerr, btw, re: your deleted "answer" with a follow-up question, note that `for item in $(anything)` is bad practice itself. See [BashPitfalls #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) describing why, and for safer alternatives, the [UsingFind](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind) sections on actions (which is to say, sections 5 through 7).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem are the date variables - and if you had read `find`'s output correctly you would have noticed that, too.

```
if test -n "$(find . -iname 'PAY*.txt' -newermt "$p_date1" ! -newermt "$p_date2" -print)";
```

Note the double quotes around the variable names.

Comment: To elaborate on that find a bit further ... the error you were seeing was because the hour component was interpreted as a bare string by find, assuming it's a path, and thus telling you that it needs to go to the front (where Roadowl's `.` went).

Comment: OMG (facepalm) - I had tried the single quotes and had got other error and never thought of double quotes around the variables as the entire command was in double quotes :-(  Clearly a noob mistake :-(

Comment: After finding the files, I also want to process one file after another in a for loop.  I tried a simple command like cp to copy the file found to some other extension but the file name is returned as ./PAY_9440734.txt.  What is the correct way to get the file name?

```
for pfile in "$(find . -iname 'PAY*.txt' -newermt "$p_date1" ! -newermt "$p_date2" -print)";
do
  echo 'File: '$pfile
  cp $pfile $pfile'.srk'
done
```

Comment: Not sure I see your problem.  `./PAY_9440734.txt` **is** a valid filename with a prepended path of `./` What issue are you facing?

Comment: I just posted it as another answer - apologies if that is not the correct way to do so.

Comment: That this works at all is a tragedy.  GNU find is playing fast and loose and violating the standard, which clearly states that the path is required.  IOW, this solution will only work with GNU find.  For portability, you must specify a path to search.  eg `find . -iname ...`